# jQuery Show and Hide Function's in Chrome

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome

I have a Div which I want to say "Loading..." while an AJAX request is being performed. I am using a Real-Time engine called APE, so when an event comes in the first thing I do is show the Div and then set the HTML to "Loading..." like this:

```
$("#test").show();
$("#test").html("Loading...");
```

And then inside my ajax function I do this (I'm using ExtJS to load it into a grid):

```
    jsonfields = Ext.decode('[' + $.ajax({
    url: "ajax.php?getsensors="+raw.deviceId, 
    success: function(data) {

        $("#test").hide();

    },
    async: false
}).responseText + ']');
```

So in Firefox the Loading div shows until it reaches the hide() function and then it disappears, in Chrome the Loading... div doesn't appear at all, and there are no errors in the console, any ideas why? Thank you!

```
   <div id="test"></div>
```

There's only one div with an ID of test, Also I have tried

```
    $("#test").html("Loading...");
```

And then tried Emptying the test with empty(), still works in Firefox and mysteriously not in Chrome. I added in Loading to the test div, just to see what happens, on initial load it says loading, and then when the first AJAX request completes it empties the div successfully but it's never repopulated with Loading again.

Comment: Are there multiple elements with an id of "test"?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo?

Comment: is it possible that ape fails to send an event to chrome? e.g. transport failed?

Comment: Well the AJAX Request completes successfully and the grid is updated, so I know the Real-time Event succeeds there's just no indicator that the request has been sent, just when it returns it repopulates the grid

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in JSFiddle, its locally hosted google apps project unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that jQuery? Because I have something similar in Viajeros.com, set up like this:

```
 $("#loading_indicator").bind("ajaxSend", function(e){
    $(this).show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
    $(this).hide();
 }).bind("ajaxError", function(){
    $(this).hide();
 });
```

The "ajaxSend", "ajaxComplete" and "ajaxError" events are fired by jQuery's internal ajax call. http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

Comment: BTW: I don't understand why is it necessary to set the HTML for the div if you have it hidden. Or does it sometimes have a different content? Also, I had troubles with empty divs in Internet Explorer and I had to set the html to "&nbsp;" or they would disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have tried a few different ways none of them work in chrome, I tried setting the text manually, then using hide/show functions, setting the html and then emptying it, ended up with a combination of both

Comment: Did you tried .css('visibility', 'visible') and .css('visibility', 'hidden')?

Comment: I just tried that, it appears that the show/hide functions are running simultaneously, because when I give show a millisecond parameter it performs the show and hide right after the ajax request comes in. Firefox is running it at the beginning of the RT Event Callback for some reason though, and Chrome doesn't run it til the request has succeeded

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The loading animation was not hidden in ajax success.
I just added 1 millisecond in the jQuery hide function.

```
function test() {
    $('#loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions.asp",
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: false,
        dataType: "text",
        data: { action: "getData" },
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            $('#loading').hide(1); // Added a millisecond
            // Do some actions
        },
        error: function (xhr, aOptions, rError) {
            $('#loading').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pete,

user a loading gif for this kind of stuff ,

add a busy indicator next to the div you clicked and once the ajax succeeds remove it
or hide it throught a class.

this is the most commpon practice

see this link

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/display-loading-gif-image-while-loading.html

Comment: Well the ajax load is triggered by a separate Real-Time event, so there's not really a "click" event which I can change the loading div with.

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes had issues with show and hide, if you don't actually pass in the paramter of fast or slow.

So:

```
$(this).show('slow);
```

or

```
$(this).hide('fast');
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this has turned up some results I see the Loading div appear and disappear, but it only happens after the request has been completed, it pops up and disappears it doesn't change at the beginning of the event

Comment: it doesn't seem to show until it reaches the hide in the ajax success callback, but the show function is at the top of the rt event, it should be the first thing that happens, before the ajax request is even sent, the RT Event is in a callback itself, I wonder if this could be causing it trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Just come across this issue myself. My solution...

To workaround this issue in Chrome, use a timeout on the AJAX call of one millisecond.

E.g.

```
$("#mySpinningLoader").show();

var t = setTimeout(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: rootPath + controllerNAction,
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(lightweightObject),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#mySpinningLoader").hide();
        }
    });
}, 1);
```